# Flutter: Split a string to all possible combinations for search

Tags: string, flutter, dart, split

When dealing with a string of numbers let's say '12345', I would do something like this

```
String number = '12345';
List<String> listnumber = number.split("");
List<int> output = [];
for (int i = 0; i < listnumber.length; i++) {
  if (i != listnumber.length - 1) {
    output.add(int.parse(listnumber[i]));
  }
  List<String> temp = [listnumber[i]];
  for (int j = i + 1; j < listnumber.length; j++) {
    temp.add(listnumber[j]);
    output.add(int.parse(temp.join()));
  }
}
print(output.toString());
```

result:

```
[1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345, 2, 23, 234, 2345, 3, 34, 345, 4, 45]
```

Perfect! that's exactly what I want. But now I can't get the same result for a string of letters.
Can someone help me achieve the same result with a string such as 'abcde'.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void main(){
String number = 'abcde';
List<String> listnumber = number.split("");
List<String> output = []; // int -> String
for (int i = 0; i < listnumber.length; i++) {
  if (i != listnumber.length - 1 ) {
    output.add(listnumber[i]); //
  }
  List<String> temp = [listnumber[i]];
  for (int j = i + 1; j < listnumber.length; j++) {
    temp.add(listnumber[j]); // 
    output.add((temp.join()));
  }
}
print(output.toString());
}
```

**Output:**

```
[a, ab, abc, abcd, abcde, b, bc, bcd, bcde, c, cd, cde, d, de]
```